# full screen background vertical align

Tags: html, css, alignment

```css
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:200,400,300,500,700);

html { 
  background: url(img/img1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.top_nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #333745;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.top_nav li {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.top_nav a {
    margin: 1.3em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
}

.top_nav li:hover {
    background-color: #ea2e49;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .top_nav ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .top_nav li {
        border: 0;
    }}

.box {
    height: 300px;
}

.center_elements {
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.center_elements p {
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    
<nav class="top_nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li class="menu1"><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
        <li class="menu2"><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
        <li class="menu3"><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
        <li class="menu4"><a href="#">menu4</a></li>        
    </ul>
 
</nav>

<div class="center_elements">
    <p>text</p>
    <button>LEARN MORE</button>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Hi guys.

I'm new to html and css.

I tried to make horizontally and vertically centered elements on the full screen background image.

Here's my code and it's pretty messed up.

Thanks for your comments guys!

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Here is [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xnx221z/) with your code in it. 
I don't understand what problem you're facing...

Comment: I'd like to put "center_elements" class on the center of my background image. Thanks.

Comment: You mean put all the content with that tag in dead center of the screen?

Comment: Yes! Right. The content and button.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Use --> [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xnx221z/2/)

That should solve your problem!

```
.center_elements {
background: none;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100px;
 left: 0;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would rather set up image for the background for body tag, not html (it's first time I can see background image for html tag, but might be wrong).

Tip for vertical align:
wrap whole content into wrapper and add css for it display: table, and display: table-cell to child element + height 100vh (vh properites are not fully supported ).

vertical-align: middle always center content exactly in the middle of parent element whatever size it has.

Sample here:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/ajL0tut6/2/